# Apply button hidden on views exposed filter on published content

Tags: ajax, views

I added an exposed filter on Published Content field in my view. It shows the apply button on preview but does not show the submit button in my actual view. Any clues.

Here is the filter in preview

[image]

Here is the missing apply button on my view

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: check it with Firebug, may be you're hiding them somewhere..

Comment: I have been using the Chrome Inspector its no where in the html

Comment: are they the same filters? why are the labels different?